# No 'server' option for importing tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

[image]

Here is what eclipse shows file -> new -> other

Comment: I believe you are looking into wrong place. It should be in `Windows-> Show  View` and search for Server. If it is not there then you need to install extension for it as mentioned in below answers.

Comment: The Windows -> Show View shows server but it's for creating one, I need to import a Tomcat

Comment: Yes  if you follow the create process, it will ask you to add your tomcat server to be added. isn't it ? I may be thinking something wrong then. I just verified, both opens the same window.

Comment: Otherwise try to install `Eclipse for Java EE developers` , Which version of eclipse you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your installation is missing the Server Tools and the JST Server Adapter Extensions feature specifically.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F